# How to Pivot row to columns for this kind of scenerio?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have a data source that returns data in the following format:

```
id | subId |  code |  name  |        col1       |    col2        |    col3
1  |     1 |   abc |    xyz |     "Whatever"    | "WhateverA"    | "WhateverB"
                            |     "Whatever2"   | "Whatever2A"   | "Whatever2B"
```

I need to make col1 row values as headers, while col2 and col3 values as subcolumns under col1 for respective rows as:

```
id | subId |  code |  name  |        "Whatever"          |        "Whatever2"         |        
1  |     1 |   abc |    xyz |   col2     |    col3       |   col2      |    col3      |
                            |"WhateverA" | "WhateverB"   |"Whatever2A" | "Whatever2B" |
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing that I know of, out of the box, that would achieve this.Here's a high level overview of a possible solution:

1. Fetch and cache the dataset on the server
2. Bind the "main\top level" data to a `GridView`
3. Using jQuery handle tr\td click events captured inside the `GridView`
4. Make an AJAX call to the server -> fetch the sub data from the cached dataset -> return it -> append the fetched result to the `GridView`

Also, instead of making an AJAX call every single time a td is clicked you can fetch all the data at once and store it in a variable or `localStorage`.I've done it this way before and there are many resources on the web with step-by-step articles how to achieve step 1 - 4.Hope it gives you an idea

Comment: Thanks for the  quick response Denis. Do you think this can be resolved using SQL pivot?

Comment: Yeah you can use pivot or some sort of temp table solution in SQL to construct the data the way you want to and then simply use the GridView to display all your data and apply CSS amd javascript to style the subheaders differently(so that they stand out)